# -m64 and -m32 flags

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw-w64

My program is 64-bit, so I have been compiling like this:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc ...
```

However now I also need 32-bit. My first thought was to use:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc ...
```

However I see that I can pass a flag and just use the original compiler:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 ...
```

This got me thinking, and I have noticed that the other compiler has a similar
option:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 ...
```

This raises some questions. Why have 2 compilers if they can both produce 64-bit
and 32-bit? Are they in fact the same, or is there some difference in the output
of the commands I have issued?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that they cannot both make 64-bit after all:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m64 alpha.c
alpha.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```